# Вывесити матрицу с помощью numpy python c разделением элементов запятой

Tags: python, numpy

После выполнения умножения дух матриц с помощью numpy python выводится результат [7.0 10.0] [15.0 22.0]. Как сделать, чтобы выводились запятые после 7.0 и 15.0. Программа вывода представлена ниже. Как исправить вывод?

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': '{:0.1f}'.format})
a, b = input().split('|')
a = [list(map(float, e.split())) for e in a.split(',')]
b = [list(map(float, e.split())) for e in b.split(',')]
result = np.dot(a,b)
for i in result: 
    print(i)
```

Comment: Пробуйте конвертировать в строку через numpy.array2string с `separator=', '`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41614898/4752653

Comment: Вообще не понятно зачем матрицу построчно циклом выводить, выводите одним принтом

Comment: Разобрался как вывести: result = result.tolist()